# getting error while installing memcached_function

Tags: mysql, ndbcluster, cache

now i am working with memcached with mysql cluster 7.2
for that i am installed

```
libevent-1.4.14b-stable.tar.gz
memcached-1.4.5.tar.gz
libmemcached-0.8.tar.gz
```

then

```
memcached_functions_mysql-0.8.tar.gz
```

i have installed first 3 successfully
but while installing `memcached_functions` with

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

i am getting error like

> checking for DEPS... configure: error: Package requirements (libmemcached >= 0.17) were not met:

can any one help me out in finding the solution...

thanks in adv

Deepak M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution for the previous case

the DEPS ERROR mainly because of not setting the path

while installing the libevent,memcached,libmemcached i gave the prefix with /usr/local path....in that path all the library files are created 
and while installing memcached function we need to set the environment variable to the path as shown below

export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local
export DEPS_CFLAGS=/usr/local
export DEPS_LIBS=/usr/local/lib

later its succesfully configured and working

regards
Deepak M